Riesz representation theorem measure is complete proof
Theorem (Riesz). Let $(X,\tau)$ a $T_2$, locally compact topological space and let $$\Lambda:\mathcal{C}_c(X,\mathbb{R}) \longmapsto \mathbb{R}$$ a positive linear functional, where $\mathcal{C}_c(X,\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all continuous functions $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ with compact support.
Then, exists a sigma algebra $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M}\supseteq \mathcal{B}(\tau)$ and exists a unique positive and complete measure $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty]$ such that:

$\mu(K)<+\infty$ for every $K\subseteq X$ compact.
$\mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(G)\hspace{5pt} | \hspace{5pt}G\in \tau, \hspace{3pt} G\supseteq E\}$ for all $E\in \mathcal{M}$ (external regularity)
$\forall E\in \mathcal{M}$ such that $E\in \tau$ and/or $\mu(E)<+\infty$, $\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(K) \hspace{5pt} | \hspace{5pt} K\hspace{2pt} \mbox{compact},\hspace{2pt} K\subseteq E\}$ (internal regularity on the open sets and on the finite measure sets)
$\int_X fd \mu =\Lambda(f), \hspace{5pt} \forall f \in \mathcal{C}_c(X,\mathbb{R})$.

First, my teacher said that the theorem is still valid (with necessary modifications) if $\mathbb{R}$ were replaced by another field ($\mathbb{C}$, for example). If we remove the positivity of the linear functional, the measure in the statement would it be a complex measure?
Then, in some preliminaries of the proof, among other things, it is proved that the measure $\mu$, if it exists, is complete. I report the explicit steps.

Uniqueness of $\mu$. (this step is ok)
Define  $$\tilde{\mu}:2^X\to [0,+\infty], \hspace{5pt} \tilde{\mu}(E)=\inf\{\tilde{\mu}(G)\hspace{5pt}|\hspace{5pt} G\in \tau, \hspace{3pt} G\supseteq E\}$$ where $\tilde{\mu}(G)=\inf\{\tilde{\mu}(V)\hspace{5pt}|\hspace{5pt} V\in \tau, \hspace{3pt} V\supseteq G\}$ that is well defined because he proved that $\tilde{\mu}$ is monotonous on the open sets.
$\tilde{\mu}$ is a positive measure. (this step is ok)
$\tilde{\mu}$ is monotonous on every $E\in \mathcal{M}$. (this step is ok)
Define the following objects:
$$\mathcal{M}_F=\left\{E\subseteq X \hspace{5pt}| \hspace{5pt} \tilde{\mu}(E)<+\infty, \hspace{3pt} \tilde{\mu}(E)=\sup\{\tilde{\mu}(K) \hspace{5pt} | \hspace{5pt} K\hspace{2pt} \mbox{compact},\hspace{2pt} K\subseteq E\}\right\}$$

$$\mathcal{M}=\{E\subseteq X \hspace{5pt} | \hspace{5pt} E\cap K\in \mathcal{M}_F \hspace{4pt} \forall K\hspace{2pt} \mbox{compact}\}$$
$$\mu=\mu_{|\mathcal{M}}$$

Completeness of $\mu$.

$E\subseteq X$ such that exists $N\in \mathcal{M}$ with $\mu(N)=0$ and $E\subseteq N$, then $\tilde{\mu}(E)=0.$
Let $K\subseteq X$ a compact set, then $E\cap K\subseteq K$. Using 4 of the previous points, we obtain that
$$0\leq \tilde{\mu}(H)\leq \tilde{\mu}(E\cap K)\leq \tilde{\mu}(E)=0, \hspace{3pt} \forall H\hspace{4pt}\mbox{compact}\hspace{4pt} |\hspace{4pt} H\subseteq E\cap K.$$
So, $\tilde{\mu}(E\cap K)=\tilde{\mu}(H)=0\hspace{3pt}\forall H\hspace{4pt}\mbox{compact}\hspace{4pt} |\hspace{4pt} H\subseteq E\cap K.$
Therefore, $\tilde{\mu}(E\cap K)=\sup\{\tilde{\mu}(H) \hspace{5pt} | \hspace{5pt} H\hspace{2pt} \mbox{compact},\hspace{2pt} H\subseteq E\cap K\}=0<+\infty$.
$\Longrightarrow E\cap K\in \mathcal{M}_F.$
$\Longrightarrow E\in \mathcal{M}.$
My fault is at this point: I can't understand why all this discussion proves that the definition of complete measure is valid. Moreover,
why $\tilde{\mu}(E)=0$ for such $E\subseteq X$?
